# Сделать выборку в таблице через внешний ключ

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы:

1. Привязка моделей и сервисов.

   **id | model_id | service_id**
2. Список сервисов.

   **id | service_name | service_prise**

Поле **service_id** сделал внешним ключом поля **id** второй таблицы.
На входе мы будем иметь **model_id**, получить надо будет данные сервисов из второй, где **service_id** первой таблицы равны **id** второй таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc_model_service 
LEFT JOIN oc_servise_list ON oc_model_service.service_id = oc_servise_list.id
WHERE `model_id` = 1
```